# Insert data from iframe/textarea into db using php and java

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I can not insert data which has already been designed/written on an iframe. My code is below.

I tried changing the iframe to a textarea. This seemed to work, but I could not add formatting like bold, italic, different font sizes, etc.

Please help correct my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
        </script>-->
    </head>
    <style>
        .image{
            border-radius:50%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function enableEditMode(){
            TextField.document.designMode="On";
        }
        //function ya buttun zote 
        function boldCmd(command){
            TextField.document.execCommand(command, false, null)
        }
        //function ya font name and fontsize
        function execCommandWithArg(command, arg){
            TextField.document.execCommand(command, false, arg)
        }
    </script>

    <body onload="enableEditMode();">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <div>
                <button name="al" onclick="boldCmd('bold');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('italic');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('justifyCenter');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-align-center"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('justifyLeft');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('justifyRight');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-align-right"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('justifyFull');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('cut');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-cut"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('copy');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('undo');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('redo');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></button>
                <button onclick="boldCmd('underline');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
                <br />

                <select onchange="execCommandWithArg('fontName', this.value);">
                    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                    <option value="Times new Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                    <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
                </select>

                <select onchange="execCommandWithArg('fontSize', this.value);">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <iframe   name="TextField" style="width:500px; height:300px;"></iframe>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","image") or die("not");   
            $TextField1=$_POST['TextField'];
            $target_dr = "upload/";
            $target_file = $target_dr . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
            $image=basename( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]); 
            $sql="INSERT INTO picha(image,file,title) 
            VALUES('$image','$target_file','$TextField1')";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        }
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM picha ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        if($result-> num_rows > 0){
            echo "<table>";
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td><img class='image' src='".$row["file"]."' height='190' width='190'/></td><td>".$row["title"]."</td>[enter image description here][1] </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>"; 
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not how iframe works. You have to use textarea.

Comment: if i use textarea the data is posted, but you can not edit (by using bold,italic, underline font size and font family) the words or sentence. how can i put textarea to accept bold, italic, etc according to my code above, example if you want to bold this "mother went to school" on textarea then you post it into database by using mysqli .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand, what is your problem. So:

1. you can't use iframe instead of textarea, you will never recieve its value on form submit.
2. if you want to add styling to content inside your textarea, you have to use some kind of WYSIWYG editor. Like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) (or alternatives).

Comment: how can i customize this WYSIWYG editor? example i need to remove file, view and Fomart.

Comment: @emmamfinanga - read the documentation or use another (there are plenty of them, just google it).

Comment: OK @shaggy,thnks

Comment: @emmamfinanga - if my answer is the one that helped you, you should accept it and mark it as the right answer.